# Unexpected error. Please report an issue on AndroidAnnotations, with the following content: java.lang.NullPointerExceptionat

Tags: android, android-annotations

I am using annotations in my android project. I am getting following error while refresh/clean the project.

null
Info

```
Unexpected error. Please report an issue on AndroidAnnotations, with the following content: java.lang.NullPointerExceptionat com.googlecode.androidannotations.helper.AnnotationHelper.extractAnnotationResIdValueParameter(AnnotationHelper.java:272)
at com.googlecode.androidannotations.helper.IdValidatorHelper.resIdsExist(IdValidatorHelper.java:45)
at com.googlecode.androidannotations.validation.ClickValidator.validate(ClickValidator.java:53)
at com.googlecode.androidannotations.validation.ModelValidator.validate(ModelValidator.java:56)
at com.googlecode.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor.validateAnnotations(AndroidAnnotationProcessor.java:414)
at com.googlecode.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor.processThrowing(AndroidAnnotationProcessor.java:364)
at com.googlecode.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor.process(AndroidAnnotationProcessor.java:341)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.handleProcessor(RoundDispatcher.java:139)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.round(RoundDispatcher.java:121)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.java:159)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.apt.pluggable.core.dispatch.IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processAnnotations(Compiler.java:809)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:428)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:364)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:178)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:301)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:60)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:254)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:173)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:629)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:172)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:255)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:258)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:362)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:545)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1975)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:524)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:115)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BuildAction.invokeOperation(BuildAction.java:222)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceAction.execute(WorkspaceAction.java:162)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceAction$2.runInWorkspace(WorkspaceAction.java:483)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Anybody have idea about this issue?

Thanks
krish

Comment: can you post your annotation code please?